# Ng-repeat delete and Edit icon visibility issue on outside click

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In ng-repeat I have a list of items and each item I have a Edit and delete icon like below,

Item1 (Edit) (Del)
Item2 (Edit) (Del)
Item3 (Edit) (Del)
Item4 (Edit) (Del)

When user click edit I changed content editable attribute to true and hide the Edit and delete options.

But when user click next Edit button or click outside I need to show to edit and delete options again.

Comment: does outside mean , outside the div or textbox

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) to detect when the element loses focus

Comment: @CodeMan can you please elaborate?

Comment: Each item I have a Edit and delete option when user click edit option I need to hide the Edit and delete options in particular item when we user click next item or user click outside I need to show again the Edit and delete options .

Answer (score 0):

Just store the state of your 'item' in item model. I believe, that yout items is just an array of json objects.

So you can do something like:

```
var vm = this;
vm.items = [...];

vm.onEdit = function(itemToEdit){

    vm.items.forEach(function(item){
       item.isEdit = item == itemToEdit;
    });

}
```

And in a view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">
    <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    <span ng-click="$ctrl.onEdit(item)"
          ng-show="item.isEdit">Edit</span>
    <span>Delete</span>
</div>
```

And about `click outside` part. You should use `ng-blur`, as @Leo mentioned, or

```
$document.on('click', function(){
    vm.onEdit();
});
```

But! It'll fire on any click, so you should attach `e.preventDefault()` on every editable field click. The approach depends on situation. `ng-blur` is better.